# how to start session for login php-mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

im trying to figure out whats wrong with my codes. everytime I try to run this. theres an error Fatal error: Function name must be a string. could someone help me. thanks

```
 <?php

$username = "root";
$password = "password";
$hostname = "localhost";

$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die("Could not connect to database");
$selected = mysql_select_db("ramon_pascual", $dbhandle);

$myusername = $_POST['user'];
$mypassword = $_POST['pass'];

$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);

session_start();
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")


$query = "SELECT * FROM ramon_account WHERE username='$myusername'  and password='$mypassword'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);

mysql_close();

if ($count==1) 
{
    $_SESSION($myusername);
    #$_SESSION['login_user'] = $myusername;
    #$seconds = 120 + time(); 
    #setcookie(loggedin, date("F jS - g:i a"), $seconds);
    header("location:admin.php");

}
else
{
    echo 'Incorrect Username or Password';
}


?>
```

there's a problem in this line in which I cant figure out why

```
$_SESSION($myusername);
```

Comment: pls read http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php this and also take a look at the examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your braces, and you are handling an array. So:

```
$_SESSION($myusername);
```

should be

```
$_SESSION['user'] = $myusername;
```

Also, make sure to start session with

```
session_start();
```

at the very top of your file!

Comment: I got new error. it says that "Can't use function return value in write context" 
the error is in $_SESSION('user') = $myusername;

Comment: You need to explain this further

Answer (score 1):

You use session as a function on line `$_SESSION($myusername)`.

It's an array, so the correct syntax is:

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $myusername;
```